# Discharge capacitor faster during reset

Tags: capacitor, analog, dac, reset

The part under consideration is [UDA1334BTS](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/UDA1334BTS.pdf) - the DAC I use in my design.

Here's the typical connection diagram:

[image]

If the circuit is being powered off, and then quickly on, the Vref voltage does not get as low as 0.75 V to get part properly reset, and the consequence is DAC output powering up with some arbitrary voltage, causing click when external interface writes initial value of 0 to the DAC. I can not state if only analog part is guilty, or digital part is also involved.

Here's the related circuit:

[image]

We can see that charge to the reference 1.25 V (analog part out of reset) takes about 1.7 seconds, and discharge to 0.75 V (analog part complete reset) takes about 1 second. My tests show that time frame, causing clicks, is actually longer than one second, thus actual reset threshold during powering down must be lower than 0.75 V.

The good thing in the circuit is that there's a system reset signal at the start of power up, which I can use to do something to this Vref input. I drew the following circuit:

[image]

and here the simulation zoomed:

[image]

Green is reset signal, blue is Vref output, and red is current through transistor's emitter.

I am looking for the feedback on this circuit, in particular:

- is it correct in general, is there any better circuit?
- what would be the best choice for transistor (I picked 2N2222 out of blue);
- any advice on resistor values?
- will the chosen values be ok for accelerated capacitor discharge not causing audible click/pop (the DAC output follows the Vref input very well)?

Edit (info for jonk): timing can be extended to the whole reset pulse width, e.g. 200-400 ms, and slope must not be sharp not to cause click/pop as DAC output follows the Vref voltage; I think small residue discharge voltage voltage (let's say, 0.4-0.7 V) would be acceptable, but must be confirmed through testing.

Comment: Depending on how strong the reset signal is (i.e. how much current it can sink), you may be able to just put a diode between reset and vref such that when reset falls it pulls vref down with it.

Comment: yeah, use a schottky diode.

Comment: Thanks. Important thing here: reset is digital, but Vref is analog, and the main task here is to ensure analog Vref is minimally affected by anything else.

Comment: the diode will isolate vref from the digital reset signal when reset is high

Comment: that red curve looks wrong, are you sure it's emitter current?

Comment: @Jasen It says Ie(Q1). LTspice won't report it that way unless it ***is*** the emitter current.

Comment: @Anonymous, you are going to fight with the Miller effect, if you want to go fast enough, on the charge storage of the BJT when used that way. This can be compensated in a variety of ways, though, and what works better for you isn't a slam-dunk. You could keep the BJT out of saturation, or use "speed-ups" to pull away the charge faster, and so on. However, you don't seem to be using fast times, so those ideas aren't yet worth exploring. How fast do you want this? And are you only focused on this kind of timing??? Can you accept a small voltage across the capacitor when discharged?

Comment: @jonk, ah yeah, i missed that the current is negative and that the top of the graph is zero.

Comment: @jonk updated the question

Comment: @Anonymous Suppose the power switch feeds a one-shot triggered by the on-off transition and its output driven low for 2 s (you specify.) If the one-shot output is high and the switch is high then the power supply is engaged. From rest, the one-shot output is high on power-up and the switch is low (off). Switching on causes both outputs to be high, so power starts up right away. If the switch is toggled low, even for a moment, the one-shot goes immediately low causing the power supply to turn off. Even if the switch is re-enabled. It requires the one-shot to rise up again before enabled.

Comment: @Anonymous Would that work? I mean if you set the time long enough so that you know, for sure, that the power supply output will decline below, say, a half-volt in that time then you can be sure of a solid reset for the ICs. It would seem to work. But the one-shot must be separately powered once the system is powered up. But that's just a big cap for its isolated supply, really. Might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use an nchannl mosfet like the 2N7002 off of the inverted reset which is fast and could also prevent noise from reaching the reference as the capacitive coupling between the gate an reference is small and high frequency (well above audio range)

[image]

Also, you might want to reduce the reference cap to 10uF (the UDA1334BTS needs at least 10uf) which would also reduce the startup time.

Answer (score 1):

Having an inverter in the circuit (your A1) is problematic because its behavior during power down in unpredictable.

A simple diode doesn’t have that problem. A standard diode will pull VREF down to about 0.7V, a schottky diode down to about 0.4V. R1 determines the rate of discharge.

When RESET_N is high (3.3V) D1 is off and completely isolated from VREF (2.1V).

I'm not convinced this will solve your audible pop problem (not an easy problem to solve), but at least this is a simpler circuit to implement your idea.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The currents are low, the speed is slow, just use whichever transistor is most convenient.

common jelly-bean NPNs include 2n3904 and BC547 and SMT versions of them.